# Can't connect to internet from my device using crossover ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, crossover-cable

I already posted in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/417729/cant-connect-or-ping-to-internet-from-my-device-using-crossover-ethernet/417735#comment443203_417735), but was closed due off-topic:

At this point I can't connect to internet from my RPi. I ask this question here and not in raspberrypi.stackexchange.com because this problem is about networking and not about the device.

To resume:

I did the following steps:
http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/454678-how-create-network-bridge-2.html#post2295540

Then, I could connect to my RPi via SSH, but I was unable to ping or resolve to google.com, so I did some steps for IP Masquerading:

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO.html

Now I can ping from my RPi to my PC and from my PC to RPi, but from my RPi to Google.com it just resolve but doesn't receive any packets from ping:

```
PING www.google.com (187.141.135.216) 56(84) bytes of data. ^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics 
--- 9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8000ms
```

I don't know what I'm missing to do.

These are my iptables rules in my PC:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What happens when you traceroute out? What are your current IP address assignments, routes, and iptables configuration?

Comment: traceroute to www.google.com (187.141.135.236), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

Comment: That's odd. Your first hop doesn't even work. Do you have a default route on the pi?

Comment: @DavidSchwarts I don't understand what do you mean with 'default route'

Comment: The "default route" specifies where packets go to if they don't match any of the other routes. What is the output of `ip route` on the pi?

Comment: default via 10.42.43.1 dev eth0 
10.42.43.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.42.43.55

Comment: I assume the PC is 10.42.43.1? What's the `iptables` configuration for masquerading on the PC?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, eth0 is 10.42.43.1

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I edited the post with the iptables

Comment: I don't see any NAT/masquerading rules!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Edited again with nat rules

Comment: There don't appear to be any rules in there.

Comment: Maybe I Undo some them with this command: iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT. I have the same result anyway

Comment: It's definitely not going to work without ip forwarding turned on and masquerading (or some other form of NAT) configured.

Comment: I don't know how to use iptables properly, so I don't really know which are the right steps to enable ip forwarding or masquerading, i just trying to follow this HOW-TO: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO.html#FAQ :S

Comment: I also tried to change to "1" the content of this file: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and is the same. But I noticed that every time I reconnect the RPi, the file goes back to '0' again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6052/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-ianenri)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm on chat again, i got offline temporally when i set the iptables rules,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:

http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2005-10/msg02384.html

> The solution does not involve IP masquerading; it only has to do with
> IP  forwarding. First we enable IP routing in YaST or by manually
> editing /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 and setting FW_ROUTE="yes".
>
> Then we have  to manually set FW_FORWARD="192.168.0.0/24,0/0". "0/0"
> is the heart of every  network in the computer. "

In my case was `FW_FORWARD="10.42.43.255/24,0/0"`, rebooted device and worked :)